# Xcode SwiftUI return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, class, swiftui

[image]

I am having the following problem.

He asks me to initialize the store, but I'm not understanding why I should do it.

Can you give me a hand?

```swift
    @State
    var repository: DummyRepo

    init?(workspace: WorkspaceDocument) {
        self.workspace = workspace
        self.repositoryModel = .init(workspace: workspace)
        
        if let folderURL = workspace.workspaceClient?.folderURL {

            let repoNameValue: String = folderURL.lastPathComponent

            self.gitClient = GitClient.default(
                directoryURL: folderURL,
                shellClient: sharedShellClient.shellClient
            )

            let branchNames: [RepoBranch] = (((try? gitClient?.getBranches(false)) ?? []).map { (branch: String) in
                 RepoBranch(name: branch)
            })

            repository = DummyRepo(repoName: repoNameValue, branches: branchNames)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are initialising `repository` inside an `if` clause but not outside it. What should the property be if the condition is false (`folderURL` is nil)? That is what the compiler wants to know.

Comment: How come if I try to initialize it first with a value, then if I try to set it inside if, the value doesn't change?
Either tried using Init or state.

Comment: Apart from the issue you cannot initialize `@State` property wrappers this way.